# Sending email from android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am referring to the below link to send email from my **android emulator** : 
[Send email without intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Everything is same as the link and it seems to work fine by looking at the LogCat logs but i never seem to receive the email !

**Below is the verbose log content from LogCat**:

```
I/System.out(815):      --------Inside onReceive of CallReceiver--------
D/CallReceiver(815):        Inside onReceive
D/CallReceiver(815):        -----Criteria matched-----
D/EmailService(815):        -----Inside On Start Command-----
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
D/GmailSenderService(815):  from = 24adithya@gmail.com, 
D/GmailSenderService(815):  recipient = 24adithya@gmail.com, 
D/GmailSenderService(815):  replyTo = 24adithya@gmail.com, 
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
I/System.out(815):      220 mx.google.com ESMTP qn3sm3719992pbc.6
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
I/System.out(815):      EHLO localhost
I/System.out(815):      250-mx.google.com at your service, [117.195.44.162]
I/System.out(815):      250-SIZE 35882577
I/System.out(815):      250-8BITMIME
I/System.out(815):      250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
I/System.out(815):      250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH"
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
I/System.out(815):      AUTH LOGIN
I/System.out(815):      334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
I/System.out(815):      MjRhZGl0aHlh
I/System.out(815):      334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
I/System.out(815):      I2EsZmF3a2VzKzE=
I/System.out(815):      235 2.7.0 Accepted
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
I/System.out(815):      MAIL FROM:<24adithya@gmail.com>
I/System.out(815):      250 2.1.0 OK qn3sm3719992pbc.6
I/System.out(815):      RCPT TO:<24adithya@gmail.com>
I/System.out(815):      250 2.1.5 OK qn3sm3719992pbc.6
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
I/System.out(815):      DEBUG SMTP:   24adithya@gmail.com
I/System.out(815):      DATA
I/System.out(815):      354  Go ahead qn3sm3719992pbc.6
I/System.out(815):      Sender: 24adithya@gmail.com
I/System.out(815):      To: 24adithya@gmail.com
I/System.out(815):      Message-ID: <1079654112.1.1344795799196.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
I/System.out(815):      Subject: Test Subject
I/System.out(815):      MIME-Version: 1.0
I/System.out(815):      Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
I/System.out(815):      Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
I/System.out(815): 
I/System.out(815):      Hi, This is 5554
I/System.out(815):      .
I/System.out(815):      250 2.0.0 OK 1344795807 qn3sm3719992pbc.6
```

I am sending the mail to myself. Has it got something to do with the emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble guys. The mail was always there in my inbox, but in some other folder due to my filters :)